# Between after_initialize and before_create callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `Booking` that `has_many: appointments`. When a `Booking` is created, I create a few `Appointments` too.

`Appointments` has an attribute `date` that needs to be populated after it is created. E.g. `before_save :set_date`.

I then need to do a validation on `Booking` when that is created to check that the appointments are sequential, which requires the date of each appointment.

1. new `Booking` initialised
2. new `Appointments` initialised
3. `Appointments` have their `date` attribute set
4. validate `Booking`.

The problem is that when the validation is occurring, the date isn't set yet. That makes sense, because the `date` is set in a `before_save` on `Appointment`, and the save hasn't happened yet.

So I changed the `before_save` to `after_initialise`. In this case, the other attributes of `Appointment` that are needed to populate date (specifically, a foreign key to a `Block`) hasn't yet been assigned to the appointment.

I want a callback between `after_initialise`, where the foreign key is set, but before `before_save`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advice to use the `before_validation` callback. If you add new validations and you need this date is set, you don't want to call `set_date` each time, or search what validation is the first called.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by explicitly calling the `set_date` function at the start of the validation, ahead of where it would usually be called.